# Adding a container causes NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uicontainerview

I am trying to add a container view to my app. However, it keeps crashing with the following error:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'containerView is required.'

I made a fresh project to test when the error occurs. When I add a container view and I assign it the class "viewController" it works fine (linked picture shows this). I then add a new UIPagecontroller class called "MainViewController" and assign this to original viewController in which the container is within - when I run this it crashes with the same error - why is this?

I haven't added any code yet so I have none to link in but heres the console error:

```
2018-12-18 21:25:38.171283+0000 caca2[19001:1863302] *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate.m:34
2018-12-18 21:25:38.190027+0000 caca2[19001:1863302] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'containerView is required.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b921e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103ff8031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b97472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000103a9b652 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001054cb49e __67-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 796
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001051b8f47 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 276
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001051b8e05 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001051b90c7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104a37f11 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 671
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104a38574 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104906123 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104906834 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001049195cc -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010488d3da -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4739
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001048925cb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1677
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104c54f7e __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000105027a39 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104c54bba -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000104c553db -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 675
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001055c6614 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 299
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001055c64ae -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001052aa75d __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001054a54b7 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001052aa627 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001050270e0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000104890eac -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000104e63bcb -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000109bc22f3 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 331
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000109bcacfa __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 225
    29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108cf67ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108cfbdb8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    31  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000109bf6470 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000109bf612e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000109bf668e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b34bb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b194af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b18a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b1830b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a48ba73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    39  UIKit                               0x0000000104894057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  caca2                               0x00000001036edd37 main + 55
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108d73955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any help or advice on how to sort this issue will be most appreciated!
Thanks

Image of simulator and xcode workspace:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, it's because what you are doing makes no sense.

- Your ViewController is a parent view controller with a single child view controller, set here by way of the embed segue; it displays the child view controller's view in the bounds of a "container view".
- A UIPageViewController is *also* a parent view controller with a single child view controller, which it will display as its page; it displays the child view controller's view in its own view's entire bounds.

These are completely different kinds of view parent view controller, managing their child and displaying its view in completely different ways. You must choose *one or the other*; a view controller cannot be both kinds of parent at the same time. But that is what you are trying to make happen.

So, if you want a custom parent view controller (the first option) you should start with the arrangement shown in your storyboard *and stop*. If you want a page view controller, you need to delete everything shown and *start* with a page view controller.

However, note also that you can use a page view controller *as* the child view controller of the original view controller. That is totally legal and very common! In fact, it is essential to be able to do that, because otherwise the page view controller will always be fullscreen, which may not be what you want.

To do that, do not change your ViewController to a UIPageViewController; change the *other* view controller in the storyboard (the child) to a UIPageViewController.

[image]

*That* is the view controller you want to change into a UIPageViewController, and it is legal to do so. Delete this view controller, drag a UIPageViewController into the storyboard, and drag a new Embed Segue from the container view to the UIPageViewController.

[image]